# Slight issue with Do While Loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

So I am writing a basic program that asks the user to input a number and the loop will continue until they enter a certain number. (25). Afterward the program will add up all of the numbers they inputted. The issue is when I type the exit number, the loop doesn't exit, and I'm not sure why.

```
double userNum = 0;
double sum = 0;

do {
    printf("Please enter a number you would like to add [Enter 25 to exit at any time]:\n");
    scanf("%f", &userNum);
    sum = sum + userNum;
} while (userNum != 25); 

printf("The sum of all the numbers you entered:%f\n", sum);
```

Also Im not sure the sum will calculate properly as Ive never been able to exit the loop.

Comment: A good compiler with warnings enabled will have reported the problem with `scanf("%f", &userNum);`  Save time!  Get a better compiler or insure your warnings are all enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using fgets for input and parse the value with sscanf. With this you could enter done or exit to terminate the loop instead of 25. The format for scanning a double is `%lf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void)
{
    char input[99] = "";
    double userNum = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    while ( 1) {
        printf("Please enter a number you would like to add [Enter 25 to exit at any time]:\n");
        if ( ( fgets ( input, sizeof ( input) , stdin))) {
            if ( strcmp ( input, "25\n") == 0) {//could use exit, done ... instead of 25
                break;
            }
            if ( ( sscanf(input, "%lf", &userNum)) == 1) {//sscanf successful
                sum = sum + userNum;
            }
        }
        else {
            break;//fgets failed
        }
    }
    printf("The sum of all the numbers you entered:%f\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong datatype, go with integers instead:

```
int userNum = 0;
int sum = 0;
do {
    printf("Please enter a number you would like to add [Enter 25 to exit at any time]:\n");
    scanf("%d", &userNum);
    sum = sum + userNum;
} while (userNum != 25);
printf("The sum of all the numbers you entered:%d\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to use a sentinel controlled loop (25 being your sentinel). Here is what I would write:

```
    #include <stdio.h>


    int main()
    {
        double userNum = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        while ( userNum != 25 ) { //sentinel controlled loop

        puts("Please enter a number you would like to add [Enter 25 to exit                at any time]:"); // puts automatically inputs a newline character
        scanf("%lf", &userNum); // read user input as a double and assign it to userNum
        sum = sum + userNum; // keep running tally of the sum of the numbers

        if ( userNum == 25 ) { // Subtract the "25" that the user entered to exit the program
        sum = sum - 25;
        } // exit the if
      } // exit while loop

        printf("The sum of all the numbers you entered:%lf\n", sum);

     } // exit main
```

OR, you can stick with do...while:

```
    // Using the do...while repetition statement
    #include <stdio.h>

    // function main begins program execution
    int main( void )
    {
       double userNum = 0; // initialize user input
       double sum = 0; //initialize sum as a DOUBLE

       do {                                               
        puts("Please enter a number you would like to add [Enter 25 to exit at any time]:"); // puts automatically inputs a newline character
        scanf("%lf", &userNum); // read user input as a double and assign it to userNum
        sum = sum + userNum; // keep running tally of the sum of the numbers


        if ( userNum == 25 ) { // Subtract the "25" that the user entered to exit the program
        sum = sum - 25;
        } // end if statement
       } while ( userNum != 25 ); // end do...while   

       printf("The sum of all the numbers you entered:%lf\n", sum);

    } // end function main
```